# Fullcalendar not being able to parse local JSON

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar

I have a controller that takes the info I need from the DB and I structure it into an array, and then into a JSON with **json_encode**.

But then, the error I get in the browser is this:
[Error from the Chrome console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPg8R.png)

This image is the JSON from my controller
[My JSON from the controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrAa3.png)

***Controller***

```
<?php
require_once '../classes/functions.php';
   
$newEvent = new calendario();
$events = $newEvent->getEvents();
$newEvent = null;

foreach ($events as $event) {
    $data[] = array(
        'title' => $event['titulo'],
        'start' => $event['inicio'],
        'end' => $event['fin'],
    );
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
}


print_r(json_encode($data));
```

***Full calendar code on my page***

```
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    if (calendarEl) {
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                locale: 'ca',
                plugins: ['dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'bootstrap'],
                timeZone: 'UTC',
                themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
                header: {
                    left: 'today, prev, next',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listMonth'
                },
                buttonIcons: {
                    prev: 'fe-arrow-left',
                    next: 'fe-arrow-right',
                    prevYear: 'left-double-arrow',
                    nextYear: 'right-double-arrow'
                },
                weekNumbers: true,
                events: {
                    url: '../controllers/getEvents.php',
                    type: 'GET',
                    format: 'json',
                    failure: function() {
                        alert('Hem trobat errors quan hem intentat exportar les visites de la base de dades!');
                    },
                },
                // events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json',
                // events: '../controllers/getEvents.php',
            });
            calendar.render();
        });
    }
```

For the sake of trying, you will see that I tried to put the demo fullcalendar uses in their examples, this works flawlessly, but my JSON does not...

Comment: I forgot to mention, i'm using XAMPP to test it in a local server. I don't know if this might be causing the error.

Comment: That `meta` tag in the output is probably being sent alongside the JSON, thus rendering it invalid.

Comment: Please read why you should not [post images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).

Comment: Image "My JSON from the controller" is not a JSON string; hence it cannot be parsed.

Comment: `print_r` is a debugging tool. Use `print` or `echo` for normal output.

Comment: Anyway yes just get rid of the meta tag from your output and you should be fine. It's unclear, from the code shown, how it got in there but presumably it's the result of something else included in your script (perhaps from functions.php or another script which was included in that).

Comment: @ADyson

First of all, thanks for responding.

Regarding the print_r thing, thanks for letting me know that it is a debugging tool.

I have deleted the meta tag, but it keeps sending ... and I guess that is what makes it not work ... how could I block the sending of the meta tag?

Comment: Have you cleared your browser's cache?

Comment: @ADyson yes, i did

Comment: Where did you delete the meta tag from? Have you verified that change has definitely been applied to your system? Have you made sure it doesn't get re-injected later on in the pipeline, e.g. by the webserver? It's hard to help you much, because all you've shown us is the code which doesn't produce that tag, so we can't really assist you much with removing it from somewhere else (that we don't have access to).

Comment: @ADyson as you said, it was a problem with "functions.php". There was a <meta> that I don't know-how was there and was causing all the issue. I'm sorry for taking your time for a problem like that. Seriously, thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the problem was with **functions.php**. As ***@ADyson*** commented, there was a meta tag there and with the require_once I was printing it every time.

Thanks to everyone that commented and helped me, and thanks again ***@ADyson***.